# Hibernate could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread on remote server

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I read the other answers on similar questions, but I haven't found a solution to my problem. I have a Tomcat7 server and a Spring application which uses Hibernate to connect to my PostgreSQL remote DB.

My framework versions are:
Spring framework 4.2.2
Spring security 3.2.5
Hibernate 4.3.6

When I run my app on localhost everything is fine, but when I deploy it on my server I receive this error on login:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    org.myapp.spring.dao.generic.GenericDAOImpl.getSession(GenericDAOImpl.java:59)
    org.myapp.spring.dao.impl.DeveloperDaoImpl.findByUsername(DeveloperDaoImpl.java:51)
    org.myapp.spring.service.impl.DeveloperServiceImpl.findByUsername(DeveloperServiceImpl.java:149)
    org.myapp.spring.web.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:23)
    org.myapp.spring.web.security.MyAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(MyAuthenticationProvider.java:30)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

I have two initializer files:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        Class[] config = {AppConfig.class};
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        Class[] config = {SecurityConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class};
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
```

and

```
@Component
public class SecurityWebApplicationInizializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

and three Config files:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "org.myapp.spring.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value="classpath:myapp.properties")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private TokenInterceptor tokenInterceptor;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor);
    }

//other methods
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.myapp.spring.web.security")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired private MyAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
@Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
    web.expressionHandler(handler);
}

@Bean
public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
    return new MyPermissionEvaluator();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/html/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/html/index", true).permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutUrl("/html/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/html/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/html/forbidden").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/html/logistic").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/html/ajax/logistic").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/html/res/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/html").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/html/**").authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/html/forbidden");
}
}
```

and, finally:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "org.myapp.spring.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean  sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.myapp.spring.model"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    try {
        sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
}
```

GenericDaoImpl is:

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements DAO<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
}
```

Every DAO extends this class and has his own @Repository annotation.

Every service is annotated as @transactional. This is the implementation of the UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, MyUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired private DeveloperService devService;
    @Autowired private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(username == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        Developer dev = devService.findByUsername(username);

        if(dev == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        MyUserDetails user = new MyUserDetails();
        user.setUsername(dev.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(dev.getPassword());
        user.setMaxAuthorityByIndex(dev.getRole());
        return user;
    }
```

I really don't know what this could be. Maybe a wrong configuration on server? To me it appears to be correct...

Comment: The problem is that you have 2 instances of your services... The one with transactions isn't used. You are component-scanning for too many things in different configurations don't do that. Your security and hibernate configuration should also be part of the root config. The servlet config should only consist of web related things (controllers, views and the infrastructure for that).

Comment: So you are saying I should use only one config file?

Comment: No I'm not... I'm saying you should be careful in what and where you are using component-scanning and that the proper type of classes should be loaded by the proper component. The `ContextLoaderListener` should, ideally, contain infrastructure services like `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory` but also services, repositories etc. Your `DispatcherServlet` should in turn contain web related things `@EnableWebMvc` and things like controllers, views but no services.

Comment: Do you have @Transactional annotation in your DeveloperService ?? If not, please put there and try again..

Comment: Any solution worked, i have same problem now. I have @Transactional at all DAO methods. I tried many other solution in stackoverflow still not working

Answer (score 0):

add this to your

```
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("current_session_context_class","org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext");
        return properties;
    }
```

Comment: This did not work, any other solution im using spring 5 , hibernate 5